# Searching for function in bash script to detect installed software packages

Tags: linux, bash, debian, fedora, redhat

I need some code which checks, if a list of packages is installed. This check should work on each linux distribution (Fedora, Arch-Linux, Debian, RedHat,...).

Actually is my script looking like that:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    # At first check, if all needed softwares are installed
    declare -a NEEDED_SOFTWARE_LIST=(bash rsync wget grep telnet)

    if [ -f /etc/debian_version ]; then
            for SOFTWARE in ${NEEDED_SOFTWARE_LIST[@]}; do
                    dpkg -l | grep -i $SOFTWARE | head -1 | if [[ "$(cut -d ' ' -f 1)" != "ii" ]]; then
                                    echo -e "$SOFTWARE is NOT installed completely! Please install it...\n";
                                    exit 1;
                            fi
            done
    else
            echo "No Debian";
    fi
```

I hope somebody can help me.

Comment: You need to analyze the file `/etc/lsb-release`. This will work on all Linux distros not just debian. Also you don't need to check if the package is installed - just install it. Package managers would not complain if a package is already installed.

Comment: Also the `grep` dance is incorrect, you should simply `dpkg -l "$SOFTWARE"` instead.

Answer (score 2):

when you say:

> This check should work on each linux distribution (Fedora, Arch-Linux, Debian, RedHat,...).

You are close to hell....

There is no easy way to do it with confidence in all distros.

with this approach, you will find that:

- there is no reliable way to guess the distro, it depends even from version to version...
- there is no reliable way to say "this package is not in the system", you will just assume that if its not installed using that distro's official package manager, it wont be there.
- sometimes, people use more than just one package manager.
- there is no reliable way to know if the package that you are talking about, has that name in that distro *(e.g. - php can be "php" in one distro, "php5" in another one, and both are "php5")*.
- this will become a hard to maintain, easy to fail, never reliable, piece of software.

so if you need to create an installer, and have dependencies, please, use a well known package manager, build a good package, and dont re-invent the wheel.

It might sound daunting, but it will pay off on the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be simpler  to just check that the binary is found?

```
declare -a NEEDED_SOFTWARE_LIST=(bash rsync wget grep telnet)
for SOFTWARE in ${NEEDED_SOFTWARE_LIST[@]} ; do
  $SOFTWARE --version |& grep "command not found" && echo "$SOFTWARE is NOT installed completely! Please install it..." && exit 1
done
```